# Python - error expected in while loop but is not shown

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

```
import os
import time

path = os.listdir('/home/dc4/Downloads/DEB/')

while True:
    check = '.part' in path[1] # x[1] == 'grape.part' (this is also a file)
    
    if check is True:
        print('True')
        time.sleep(5)
```

I am using **os** module and its **listdir()** method to list all files in the variable **path**,
the first line inside while loop checks if the file extension **.part** is in the string **'grape.part'** and if the file is located in the **path** directory.

In this image --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHDRh.png **.part** is in the **'grape.part'** which is also in the **path** directory, the if statement checks this and it prints **True** and uses the **time** module to sleep every 5 seconds as expected.

However if I remove **grape.part** from the **path** directory while the program is running there is no error which I am expecting, it just continues printing **True** until I stop the program -->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxqme.png

If I stop and start the program when **grape.part** is not in the **path** directory only then do I get the error why and how do I fix this? (I don't know if I explained the issue well I'm pretty new to python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to check specifically for that file or any file with that extension? This first solution checks for the file.

I've added an `else` statement so the program knows to `break` when the file is removed. I've also used `Path` from `pathlib` to change how you check that your file exists.

The reason your implementation didn't work is that you were checking whether the `check` list you created contained the file and not the directory itself.

```
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path('/home/dc4/Downloads/DEB/grape.path')
while True:
    check = file_path.exists()

    if check is True:
        print('True')
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        # print('False')
        break
```

Consider also, this alternative implementation, which checks for any file with the extension:

```
import os
import time

while True:
    if any(fname.endswith('.path') for fname in os.listdir('.')):
        print('true')
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        # print('false')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` returns a list of the items in a directory when it was called. Since this is just a regular `list`, it will not change automatically. For your desired behavior, put the `os.listdir` call inside the loop.

```py
while True:
    path = os.listdir('/home/dc4/Downloads/DEB/')
    check = '.part' in path[1] # x[1] == 'grape.part' (this is also a file)
    
    if check:
        print(True)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the path once. So, it does not change when you move the file. Putting the path inside of the loop will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You must add listdir inside the loop so it can refresh the file contents the script has saved.

Full code:

import os
import time

while True:

```
path = os.listdir(r'/home/dc4/Downloads/DEB/')

check = '.part' in path[1]

if check is True:
    print('True')
    time.sleep(5)
```